# How to make layout with tabs in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have no idea where to start, to achieve this layout

[image]

i want to have a HorizontalScrollView on the top which has some 4-6 buttons/images which on click changes the body of the layout to a different ListView depending on the button/image clicked. I have no idea if this is done in the same activity or different activities.

i have been searching for tabbed layouts and could't get what i wanted.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments) could help.

Comment: but i read fragments are for android 3.0 and +. But the application pic i pasted works on my 2.3.3 device. are you sure fragments is the only way to do this??

Comment: Fragments can be used on older devices using the Compatibility libraries.

Comment: I didnt ask you to do my project. In the first line itself i told "i have no idea where to start". all i needed is a name for that layout or what to use to get that layout. Like cosmincalistru or Raghav sood said, "use fragment" helped me.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc this question is not really suitable for [SO]. While I understand your problem it does show a lack of research, which is always met with resistance here.  Fragments are extremely common in Android programming.  For more information on the platform read [developer guides](http://developer.android.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `Near by - Offer - Cards`, that is [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)
The part `Near by - Shopping - Electronics` seem like `tabhost` with custom `tabwidget`. Normal, tabhost fit all tabwidgets in screen but if you want it scrollable. Add tabwidget in `HorizontalScrollView` and add `android:fillViewport="true"`. Detail in here  [Scrolling Tabs in Android](http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/)